# Rename support for derived names in DrRacket

Tags: racket, rename, automated-refactoring

When a macro produces bindings using derived names, these are not considered references to the original name (which is expected behaviour). However, renaming doesn't work on the derived names.

Here is a simple macro example:

```
(define-syntax (my-syntax stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ name)
     (with-syntax ([get-name (format-id #'name "get-~a" #'name)])
       #'(begin
           (define name 42)
           (define (get-name) name)))]))
```

In the code below, renaming `foo` on the first line to `bar` with `right-click → Rename foo` correctly renames foo on the second line, but fails to rename `get-foo` on the third line.

```
(my-syntax foo)
foo
(get-foo)
```

Is there for example some kind of syntax property that can be attached to `foo` and `get-foo` to provide a rename-helper (that could produce a list of original / renamed pairs)?

As a last resort, I could use a fixed convention, and use a reader extension to actually expand `get-foo` to `(get foo)` early on, although I'm not sure if that would even work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very nice question.

I got a tip from the author of DrRacket.
The 'sub-range-binders property should do the trick:

[http://docs.racket-lang.org/tools/Check_Syntax.html?q=sub-binder#%28idx._%28gentag.*28.*%28lib._scribblings%2Ftools%2Ftools..scrbl%29%29%29](http://docs.racket-lang.org/tools/Check_Syntax.html?q=sub-binder#%28idx._%28gentag._28._%28lib._scribblings%2Ftools%2Ftools..scrbl%29%29%29)

Comment: It must be a recent feature, as it doesn't work on racket 5.3.6 (packaged on Ubuntu 14.04) but it does work on version 6.1.1. Installing version `racket-6.1.1-i386-linux-ubuntu-precise.sh` on 14.04 was a breeze (`chmod +x racket-6.1.1-i386-linux-ubuntu-precise.sh && ./racket-6.1.1-i386-linux-ubuntu-precise.sh) and seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, identifiers follow the Lisp tradition that goes all the way back to 1958, in which symbols are atomic, and are not treated as if they had constituent parts. So Racket doesn't have any information about the `foo` within `get-foo`. It only knows about `get-foo`.

Comment: Identifiers in Racket are not represented as symbols. Identifers are represented as syntax objects. Syntax objects carry lexical information as well as the name. DrRacket can use such lexical information for various purposes, so Georges' idea is spot on.

Comment: So you're telling me a syntax-object representing an identifier can hold different lexical information for one part of the name than it does for another? Is this functionality exposed to the programmer?

Comment: Almost. The identifier has the usual lexical information attached. The programmer can attach further properties to a syntax object though. In this case adding the property key 'sub-range-binders property has a value, that holds lexical information for the various parts of the identifier. DrRacket will react on that. Say you have a struct named foo with a field bar. The accessor is called foo-bar. If you use DrRacket to rename bar to baz, DrRacket will, based on the information attached to foo-bar, rename foo-bar to foo-baz. It's pretty sweet.

Comment: Which part of the identifier provides the lexical info if I call `(datum->syntax stx 'xyzzy)` where `stx` is an instance of `foo-bar`?

Comment: You need to use argument four of datum->syntax to give the resulting syntax object a property (in this case 'sub-range-binders). The value associated to 'sub-range-binders contains the information.